# Google Glass Quickstart Java HTTP ERROR 503 Error Service_Unavailable

Tags: google-app-engine, google-mirror-api, google-glass

Whenever I try to run the java mirror quick start master on localhost:8080 and I am getting.

```
            HTTP ERROR: 503
            Problem accessing /. Reason:
            SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
            Powered by Jetty://
```

I am using the mav jetty:run in the command line. 
I do not know where I am going wrong. I am afraid the solution is hitting me in the face, and i can't see it.

Any Help would be appreciated thank you in advance.

```
 Scanning for projects...

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Building glass-java-starter 0.1-SNAPSHOT
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------

 >>> maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (default-cli) @ glass-java-starter >

 --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ glass-j
er ---
 Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
 Copying 1 resource

 --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ glass-java-s
-
 Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

 --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @
va-starter ---
 Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
 skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\mirror-quickstart-java-master\s
esources

 --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ glas
arter ---
 No sources to compile

 <<< maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (default-cli) @ glass-java-starter <

 --- maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (default-cli) @ glass-java-starter -
 Configuring Jetty for project: glass-java-starter
 Webapp source directory = C:\mirror-quickstart-java-master\src\main\we

 Reload Mechanic: automatic
 Classes = C:\mirror-quickstart-java-master\target\classes
 Logging to org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortba
4jLog
 Context path = /
 Tmp directory =  determined at runtime
 Web defaults = org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
 Web overrides =  none
 web.xml file = C:\mirror-quickstart-java-master\src\main\webapp\WEB-IN

 Webapp directory = C:\mirror-quickstart-java-master\src\main\webapp
 Starting jetty 6.1.26 ...
 jetty-6.1.26
NG] Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebA
@6d9ef759{/,C:\mirror-quickstart-java-master\src\main\webapp}
ang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.glassware.SignOutServlet
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadCla
rstStrategy.java:50)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRe
244)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRe
230)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLo
:401)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLo
:363)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.
)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6MavenConfiguration.parseAnnotations
venConfiguration.java:141)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configure(Abst
guration.java:119)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXm
ation.java:180)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configureWebAp
tConfiguration.java:96)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration.configureWebApp(Config
ava:149)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.
)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.ja

  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:

  at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6P
ppContext.java:115)
  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.ja

  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollect
152)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(Context
llection.java:156)
  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.ja

  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollect
152)
  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.ja

  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.ja

  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.ja

  at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServ
32)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJett
a:454)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMo
96)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJett
java:210)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:

  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Defa
luginManager.java:106)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecu
208)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecu
153)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecu
145)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildPr
ecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildPr
ecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreade
fecycleStarter.java:183)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifec
er.java:161)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorIm
7)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAc
l.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(L
ava:290)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.

  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
.java:414)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.ja

 Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
 Started Jetty Server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the web app is having trouble finding a declared servlet SignOutServlet.

This servlet was removed [a few commits back](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java/commit/e251670955bc506628418451acdcda50418735c5), and it looks like your web.xml file is out of sync with the available source. You have a couple of options for resolving this issue:

1. Make a new clone / download the zip file for the latest version of the [Java quick start](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java) (this is probably the easiest solution)
2. Remove all references to SignOutServlet from `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` as was done in [this commit](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java/commit/e251670955bc506628418451acdcda50418735c5).

   ```
     <url-pattern>/attachmentproxy</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <!-- remove stuff below here -->
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>signout</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.google.glassware.SignOutServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>signout</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/signout</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <!-- remove stuff above here -->


   <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   ```

Once you've removed those dependencies, do a clean before you build for good measure:

```
$ mvn clean jetty:run
```

Comment: I made sure to remove the SignOutServlet from the web.xml and I did a mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies package, and now it's working. thank you Jenny. I wish I could upvote this answer but I don't have enough points.